# Add each EventListener to the given JComponent

Tags: jcomponent, listeners

I'm making a JComponentFactory and a subclass of that is a JLabelFactory. There is a create(Set listeners) method in JLabelFactory and what it's supposed to do is use the given method (below) to add each listener in the set to the created JLabel. I can do it this way:

```
protected boolean addSpecificListeners(JLabel label, Set<EventListener> listeners) {
    for(EventListener e: listeners){
        if(e instanceof MouseMotionListener){
            label.addMouseMotionListener((MouseMotionListener)e);
        }
        else if(e instanceof MouseWheelListener){
            label.addMouseWheelListener((MouseWheelListener)e);
        }
        else if....
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be a smart way to me. Especially since I will have to go to all the possible Listener types for EVER JComponent I want to add listeners to. Is there a smarter way to do this?